# How to get started on SOAP service on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: soap, windows-mobile, wsdl

Hey guys, I'm a student that is trying to develop a Windows Phone 7 app that uses a free web service that can be accessed via SOAP protocol. They have the web service address and the .wsdl address.

I'm pretty confused since all that I've seen mentions .asmx instead of .wsdl, can somebody point me to the right direction to start implementing the web service usage in my app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Anything you see about .asmx you should ignore. That's old technology. You will probably want to use WCF, but I don't know how it is limited on Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is the standard for SOAP-based web service description. It's an xml-based description of webservices that allows client proxy code generation across platforms. ASMX is just an extension for a webservice page. They're separate entities.

Comment: And, ASMX is now considered "legacy technology", so don't bother with it.

Comment: @John: Unless the service already exists and he needs to get data from it, which is what the question implies.

Comment: No the service only mentions the .wsdl and the webservice address, what I meant was that all the tutorials and info I found talked about "asmx" when using SOAP

Comment: @ctacke: even in that case, he should ignore anything about .ASMX and simply use WCF technology to access the old service.